# how to extend the window on Chromebook with dual monitors?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am trying to create a single chrome app to display(by using 3840x1080 resolution) on both monitors.

when I try to move a window, from one monitor to other, I am able to see only half of the window on one screen. Is there any settings to make it work like extended monitors

[image: Dual monitors with chromebook- only half of browser is seen on second monitor]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Packaged App and Dual Monitors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328295/chrome-packaged-app-and-dual-monitors)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that; this is specific to Chrome OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently a limitation of Chrome OS.

Keyword **was**: [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365662) is marked as Verified (fixed) in May. However, see this comment:

> Please note that this feature was developed for specific enterprise use case, and will always be behind a flag. In other words, this will not be on by default for general use.
>
> You can enable it using about:flags starting from M44 though.

So, to use this, you apparently need to set the "Enable unified desktop mode" flag in `chrome://flags/`. I can't confirm since I don't have a Chrome OS device to test.

Comment: I enabled the setting but it is still the same (OS Chrome version 45)

Comment: You may want to try and leave a comment on that bug then.

Comment: To clarify, you need to do 2 things:
1. Set the flag (according to above)
2. Enable it in settings

Maybe this is what confused @Amanda?